# Create DocumentRoot automatically

Tags: windows, apache, command, line

We've installed Xampp on our students VM.
The problem is that we can't set a static DocumentRoot in our httpd.conf. So we have to dynamically create the DocumentRoot directory. For example: J:/Apache where Apache is the directory which should be created automatically.

Is there a way to do it? Or maybe to execute an mkdir command during the start?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do, is creating a .sh-file that includes the part you need of a requested URI.

Let's say you build a script that is called by

```
http://example.com/create-DR/username
```

And let's also assume that you set an environment variable depending on the requested URI:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/create-DR/(.+)$" DR_User=$1
```

I think that you should be able to use this environment variable in you shell-sript with **$DR_User**

The script can also be executed automatically if you put it in your cgi-bin folder and besides setting DR_User also redirect the request to the script (would do that with [P] to hide what you are doing):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/create-DR/(.+)$
RewriteRule .? /path/to/cgi-bin/create-user.sh [P,L]
```

So far you have created new folders and set an EV dynamically. The downside currently is that it can be used for creating exorbitant many folders. I'd suggest you put a safety mechanism in play. For example you only allow a specific IP (the teachers' PC) to execute the script:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/create-DR/(.+)$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^10\.11\.12\.13|4$
RewriteRule .? /path/to/cgi-bin/create-user.sh [P,L]
```

This allows the script to be executed from IPs 10.11.12.13 and 10.11.12.14.

Now you should enable your students to call their folders.
To handle the request you build a default-vhost (myb for port 80) with VirtualDocumentRoot to handle them for each user dynamically:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName testsites.example.com
  ServerAlias *.test.example.com
  VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/dev/%1
</VirtualHost>
```

That would mean that your students call .test.example.com and the first part (given by %1) will be taken for the VirtualDocumentRoot --> the

I don't know the folder, but read [THIS](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html#interpol) to understand how to address the specific folders. There are several examples to determine the right syntax.

Never tried or tested this, but in theory that should be the way to do it. I would appreciate some feedback on how that worked for you and error messages received, if it didn't work.

**EDIT**

There are some modules required for this,at least these:
mod_rewrite
mod_setenvif
mod_alias
mod_cgi